# Why is Apache not saving the XML file from ajax POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, apache, post

i am a little lost with an problem with my apache server.

My goal is to provide a XML editor in the browser that alters a XML file on the server.

I use [jquery.xmleditor](https://github.com/UNC-Libraries/jquery.xmleditor) to provide this interface.
With the following line i can specify a file path

```
    ajaxOptions : {
        xmlUploadPath: "file.xml",
        xmlRetrievalPath: "file.xml",
        xmlRetrievalParams : null
    },
```

When executing a submit on the webpage, the XML file is transmitted using a POST-request. I can see Apache server log with mod_dumpio that the POST-request is successful but the file.xml is not updated with the new values.

I already found threads that call out on file permissions but a checked that already and the file can be written by the apache www-data user.

Why is the new content not written to the file.xml?

Comment: An xml file is a static resource. You need to send to an endpoint that runs executable code to modify the file

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate further? Do i have to write a PHP script that overwrites the file ?

Comment: Yes.... php or other programming language available to you on the server

Comment: Depending on your requirements you could also look into WebDAV, but writing some code will be much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, i found a solution here: https://thisinterestsme.com/receiving-xml-via-post-php/